# Type '{' '}' in url

Tags: hyperref, urls

I would like to type brace symbol inside a URL using the url or hyperref
package.
Is there a way to do that ?

(the idea is to typeset REST-like URL, as for example,

```
http://foo.bar/orders{orderID}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just type the URL:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\url{http://foo.bar/orders{orderID}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `hyperref` it's the same, but the result is an invalid URL, I guess.

Comment: hum ... I am confused .. I spent one hour trying to solve a non-existent problem. Thanks egreg.

Comment: @jean In general, though, adding a backslash before the brace will escape it and allow you to display a curly brace on screen, e.g., `\{Hello\}`.

Answer (score 6):

With `hyperref`, for fun (egreg was tooooo fast with `url` ;)...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \href{http://foo.bar/orders{orderID}}{\texttt{http://foo.bar/orders\{orderID\}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\url{http://foo.bar/orders{orderID}}`, no need for `\href` here.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Correct, but you know egreg was faster than me in typing. Hence I thought of alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with such symbols as {, }, [, ] in hyperlinks inside `\footnote`. They don’t work even when are replaced with %7B, %7D, %5B, %5D. Outside of `\footnote`, the following is okay

`\href{https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1913?tify=%7B"pages":%5B602\%5D,"view":"info"\%7D}{Mechanik der festen K\"{o}rper im plastisch-deformablen Zustand}`

but inside it results in *"Runaway argument?"*

The solution is to precede `%`s with `\`

`\footnote{\textbf{R. von~Mises}. \href{https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1913?tify=\%7B"pages":\%5B602\%5D,"view":"info"\%7D}{Mechanik der festen K\"{o}rper im plastisch-deformablen Zustand~// Nachrichten von der K\"{o}niglichen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu~Göttingen, Mathematisch-physikalische Klasse, 1913. Seiten 582\hbox{--}592.}}`