# Type uneven number of curly braces '{' '}' in URL using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, urls, url

My question is somewhat similar to this one: [Type '{' '}' in url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162248/type-in-url)
However, how can I write an uneven number of curly braces, e.g.:

```
\url{http://example.org/foo/\{bar}
```

The documentation of the URL package says, one should use another char than {}. However as soon as I load hyperref, the URL functional seems to be overwritten. The only working code I could produce was something like

```
\url{http://example.org/foo/\%7Bbar}
```

which is still syntactically correct but produces the %7B in the output (where I want to have the human-readable '{').

Minimal example which does not compile correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
   foo \url+http://example.org/foo/\{bar+ bar
\end{document}
```

If I remove hyperref, the example works…

Comment: Instead of curly braces, use a non-special character that doesn't occur inside the URL string as the delimiter at both the beginning and the end of the string. E.g., with the `+` symbol as the delimiter character, write `\url+http://example.org/foo/\{bar+`. Of course, the `url` package must be loaded for this to work. (Aside: A "special" character, in a TeX context, is one of `% & # \ _ ^ { }`.

Comment: this does only work for the url package. If i load hyperref, I get a compile error

Comment: As I wrote very explicitly in my earlier comment, the `url` package must be loaded for my suggestion to work. If you don't load the `url` package, I can see no reason for why my suggestion would work. If you want to (or need to) load the `hyperref` package as well, you are of course free to do so. Just be sure to load `hyperref` *after* `url`.

Comment: That's what I tried. Minimal example: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{url} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document}    foo \url+http://example.org/foo/\{bar+ bar \end{document}` results in `foo +http://example.org/foo/{bar+ bar` (note the additional +-sign, I think hyperref destroys the functionality of url)

Comment: You are right that `hyperref` modifies `\url` in a way breaking its usage with a delimiter. It provides `\nolinkurl` with comment `save the meaning of the original \cmd{\url} in \cmd{\nolinkurl}` but this does not work for usage with delimiter.

Comment: The `hyperref` definition of `\nolinkurl` uses `\hyper@n@rmalise` which fetches an argument (`#2`) and is not thought out to be used with delimiter syntax for `\url` (because `#2` ends up being the delimiter and not the URL).

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround (perhaps a better way exists, not yet investigated) you can use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
   foo \href{http://example.org/foo/\%7Bbar}{\texttt{http://example.org/foo/\{bar}} bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image is from usage of Acrobat Reader. In another PDF viewer, the tooltip displayed a brace, not `%7B` in the displayed URL with yellow background.

Comment: Nice solution, however it breaks the linebreak algorithm which should break urls on / characters and does not add a hyphen…